# How to allow soft device placement when deploying a TensorFlow model to GCP?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to deploy a TensorFlow model to GCP's Cloud Machine Learning Engine for prediction, but I get the following error:

```
$> gcloud ml-engine versions create v1 --model $MODEL_NAME --origin $MODEL_BINARIES --runtime-version 1.9

Creating version (this might take a few minutes)......failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.versions.create) Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: Loading servable: {name: default version: 1} failed: Invalid argument: Cannot assign a device for operation 'tartarus/dense_2/bias': Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:3 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.\n\t [[Node: tartarus/dense_2/bias = VariableV2[_class=[\"loc:@tartarus/dense_2/bias\"], _output_shapes=[[200]], container=\"\", dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[200], shared_name=\"\", _device=\"/device:GPU:3\"]()]]\n\n (Error code: 0)"
```

My model was trained on several GPUs, and it seems like the default machines on CMLE don't support GPU for prediction, hence the error I get. So, I am wondering if the following is possible:

- Set the `allow_soft_placement` var to `True`, so that CMLE can use the CPU instead of the GPU for a given model.
- Activate GPU prediction on CMLE for a given model.

If not, how can I deploy a TF model trained on GPUs to CMLE for prediction? It feels like this should be a straightforward feature to use, but I can't find any documentation about it.

Thanks!

Comment: I've been investigating and I think that the error is in the model itself or how it's saved, as you can use GPUs when [deploying versions](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/deploying-models#understanding_the_savedmodel). Maybe the error comes from how you are using that GPU, could you add a snipped of that part for having more info? This is a wild guess, but can you try it with `tf.device("/gpu:3")`, as per [documented](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-gpus#gpu_device_strings)

Comment: For saving the model, check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#structure_of_a_savedmodel_directory).

Comment: In case this clarifies my question: I am using `tf.device("/gpu:x")` when saving the model. If I export the model without the explicit device placement, everything works. I am wondering if there's a way to deploy such model for prediction without having to re-export it.

Comment: Hi Oriol, you need to [export](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/deploying-models#before_you_begin) your model before you deploy it to Cloud ML Engine for predictions.

Comment: To be clear, I already exported the model. The question is how to use the soft placement without having to re-export the model. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: It seems that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `gcloud ml-engine versions create`, but when you deploy a training job with `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training`, you can add a `config` flag that identifies a configuration file.

This file lets you identify the target machine for training, and you can use multiple CPUs and GPUs. The documentation for the configuration file is [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs).

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know how to force the prediction to use the CPU there (`allow_soft_placement=True`) or to force the GPU usage. It'd be great to have an example for this.

Comment: As I understand it, you can't configure devices for prediction jobs. Only training jobs. Prediction is always CPU-based.

Comment: That's what I thought too. So, is there any way to allow soft device placement when submitting the model for prediction?